# Assign string array as a textbox C#

Tags: c#, .net, forms, text, controls

I'm trying to make a dynamic textbox from string arrays, but when I run the program I got error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

This is my code:

```
public void GetInf(Form oFrm, string[] sArray) { 
try
{
     FormPrev = oFrm;
     sObjArr = sArray;
     this.ShowDialog();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     throw new Exception(ex.Message);
}

private void dgBrowse_CellMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
     for (int i - 0; i < sObjArr.Length; i++)
     {
          **FormPrev.Controls[sObjArr[i]].Text = "test";**
     }
}
```

It gives me an error message *"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"* on FormPrev.Controls[sObjArr[i]].Text = "test";
sorry for my english

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of the code - post the code itself (with code formatting)

Comment: thanks marco, this is my first time using stackoverflow to ask question.